# Cakephp find not returning the complete string

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a model `BudgetsProduct` that is associated with the model `Product`, but it's returning the `Product` data cutting the first character on fields `id` and `title`, how you can see above.

Notice that `BudgetsProduct.product_id` is `7724` and its returning the correct associated product row, but trimming the first character like `Product.id` is returning just `724`.

```
'BudgetsProduct' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'budget_id' => '2',
            'product_id' => '7724',
            'quant' => '3.00',
            'price' => '3175.00',
            'discount' => '0.00',
            'discount_type' => '%',
            'product_options' => 'null',
            'active' => '1',
            'creator' => null,
            'created' => '2014-08-27 15:52:35',
            'modifier' => null,
            'modified' => '2014-08-27 15:52:35',
            'Product' => array(
                'id' => '724',
                'title' => 'onjunto Pina (03)',
                'opt_title' => null,
                'parent_id' => null,
                'stock' => false,
                'active' => '',
                'creator' => null,
                'created' => '013-12-11 10:53:30',
                'modifier' => null,
                'modified' => '014-04-09 15:44:24'
            )
        )
```

Comment: are you using find with containable or joins? Also, its just a matter of the *correct* Product getting returned, but the id trimmed, or is the *incorrect* product (id 724) been fetched?

Comment: I'm using the containable. It's the correct product with the `id` and `title` trimmed.

Comment: Can you get the raw SQL and see if it happens when you execute it directly on the DB?